# Solve this usecase with solr

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrnet, solrcloud

I am indexing small length documents in **Solr** 4.* . I have custom `Similarity Class` to calculate `fieldNorm`. I have set predefined `fieldNorm` for `documents having terms less than 10`.

Consider I have two documents in field **searchinme**

```
Doc 1: Work in RevLeg
Doc 2: Work in RevLeg Project is RevLeg.
```

Now When I search for `"working in revleg"`, then I am getting following sequence.

```
Top 1: Work in RevLeg Project is RevLeg
Top 2: Work in RevLeg.
```

My expectation is to get result like this

```
Top 1: Work in RevLeg
Top 2: Work in RevLeg project RevLeg.
```

I did some analysis and found because of word `RevLeg` found in doc 2 twice and in doc 1 its is once, then Doc 2 getting higher score because of higher TF.

**Even though I have higher FieldNorm score for Doc 1 than Doc 2** .

How should I solve this use case?

Comment: usually final score is a multiplication of fieldNorm and TF and IDF, so fieldNorm have less control on final score. I don't understand why you want to fix scoring with fieldNorm values

Comment: I predefined "fieldNorm" score because my documents are short length (in dex terms less than 10). If I donot fix fieldNorm then it will be same (almost same) for documents having indexed terms between 1 - 10 .. Which sometimes causing  length with more terms (say 7 terms ) to appear atop of length of less number of terms ( 5 terms ) ..